# Enterprise Library 5 exception block doesn't write log to DB when i add some additional data to exeption.Data

Tags: logging, exception, app-config, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise library 5 for managing Exception handling, logging.
I set 2 Handler for All Exceptions in default Policy of Exception Handling Settings,first log Exception in DB and second Wrap handler and Throw New Exception.
and i wrote this code for test logging the exceptions:

```
public void Save(OrderHeader orderHeader)
{
....    
                try
                {
                    throw new Exception("Test");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Dictionary<object, object> parameters = new Dictionary<object, object>();
                    //e.Data["Order"] =  orderHeader.OrderId;
                    //e.Data["Customer"] =  orderHeader.Customer;
                    ExceptionManager exManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
                    if (exManager.HandleException(e, "Policy"))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

}
```

i want to save additional information to logged data, for example orderHeader.OrderId, orderHeader.Customer. 
so i change my text formatter template to(add Extended properties):

```
Message: {message}{newline}
Category: {category}{newline}
Priority: {priority}{newline}
EventId: {eventid}{newline}
Severity: {severity}{newline}
Title:{title}{newline}
Machine: {localMachine}{newline}
App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}
ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}
Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}
Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}
Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}
Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}
```

with these code and template, everything is OK and exception loges into Database(i don't write any code to write additional data still), but when i uncomment  two commented line of my code, nothing saves to DB!
code that does not works is:

```
public void Save(OrderHeader orderHeader)
    {
    ....    
                    try
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Test");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Dictionary<object, object> parameters = new Dictionary<object, object>();
                        e.Data["Order"] =  orderHeader.OrderId;
                        e.Data["Customer"] =  orderHeader.Customer;
                        ExceptionManager exManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
                        if (exManager.HandleException(e, "Policy"))
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
    }
```

also this is my app.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="rolling.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment"
        rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener for All Events" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="LogAllEvents.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollInterval="Day" />
      <add name="Database Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        databaseInstanceName="LoggingDB" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"
        addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter with Extended properties" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
        name="Text Formatter with Extended properties" />
    </formatters>
    <logFilters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.LogEnabledFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        enabled="true" name="Logging Enabled Filter" />
    </logFilters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Exceptions">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener for All Events" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener for All Events" />
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener for All Events" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                logCategory="Exceptions" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling"
                formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
                priority="0" />
              <add name="Wrap Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WrapHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                exceptionMessage="!در برنامه رخ داد {handlingInstanceID} خطاي"
                wrapExceptionType="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="LoggingDB" />
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ERPContext" connectionString="Data Source=ASPS51;Initial Catalog=L4;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa_l4;password=1234;application name = LEVEL4"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="LoggingDB" connectionString="Data Source=ASPS51;Initial Catalog=Logging;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa_l4;password=1234;application name = LEVEL4"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <!--<supportedRuntime version="v4.4" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.4"/> -->
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EnvDTE" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Is there any idea?

Comment: Do you see any error in the LogAllEvents.log?  This is where any error information should be logged.  Also, check if there is a null key in the ExtendedProperties since that is an [existing bug](https://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/31624) that will cause the formatter to fail.

Comment: No, in the LogAllEvent.log isn't any error information, and there isn't any null key, in my ExtendedProperties.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote key but I meant value.  If any item value in the Extended Properties is null then it will fail.  Could one of the data values be null?

Comment: Thanks Tuzo, thats right, some of my values was null, after checking them, extended properties has been inserted in DB, but this problem has any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tuzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114664/tuzo) said in comments: "If any item value in the Extended Properties is null then it will fail"
, one of my extended property values was null. i checked values for null and then the log record saved to DB.